# Is it a good idea to always read charge and orbitals if I am working on similar systems?

Tags: vasp, computational-chemistry, crystallography, elasticity

For example, if I am investigating of the elastic properties of a crystal by doing a lot of computations of crystals applied with small strain.
Also, is it a good idea to read charge and orbitals when doing step-by-step structural relaxation?

Comment: Normally a plot charge - bulk modulus for instance could be interesting for your personal understanding, but trivial for some crystals and inaccurate especially for a plane wave basis set.